# Component based development, should component be frameworkless.

Tags: user-interface, components, webpack

Scenario is a business component based web development team. Components are developed by different team members sharing common understanding of how the component system should work.

One solution is to let container be responsible for grid, core ui styling, maybe some other js components like bootstrap.  Then the issue is, if we depend on such a runtime. The module will not be so isolated as expected.

Another thought is to use webpack as a build tool at the overall application build time. Then we are able to rely on build time to avoid duplicated resources. This would be a reasonable solution only that we may have to import multiple modules for each component.

Any other thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you could make each component a commonjs component, and use webpack to bundle them as needed for each application. How our company works is that we have a big library of components made in commonjs. We have multiple apps, and for each app we use webpack to bundle the required components/modules. Each 'App' is a new entry point in webpack.

Hope that helps.

Comment: we are doing something similar.  our usage case is more like a 3rd party scenario.  we have no control about the container app.  if we use a framework in component, it is very possible to bring a conflict or at least confusion.  we just make some compromise with the product team that, we could claim that we need framework like angular, ember.  they would decide if our artifact could be used, if not, they would possibly make its own wrapping with our base libraries.